# How can mutable variables be treated as "volatile" for static type checking?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider this class which has a variable `state` that is compared twice in the method `check_twice` and its value is changed in between the two checks by the method `work`:

```
import enum


class State(enum.Enum):
    INIT = 0
    DONE = 1


class Worker:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.state = State.INIT

    def work(self):
        self.state = State.DONE

    def check_twice(self) -> None:
        if self.state is State.DONE:
            print("DONE at first try")
            return

        self.work()

        if self.state is State.DONE:
            # according to mypy this will not happen
            x: int = "x"  # mypy will not check this
            print("DONE at second try")
            return

        print("not DONE after second try")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = Worker()
    w.check_twice()
```

As expected, when executing this, the output is

```
$ python3 volatile.py 
DONE at second try
```

because at the beginning of `check_twice`, the variable was still `INIT`, but at the second check it has been changed to `DONE` by `work()` "in the background".

However, according to mypy (version 1.5.0), when using the `--strict-equality` option, the branch which prints this output is unreachable,

```
$ mypy --strict-equality volatile.py 
volatile.py:23: error: Non-overlapping identity check (left operand type: "Literal[State.INIT]", right operand type: "Literal[State.DONE]")  [comparison-overlap]
```

because mypy thinks that if `state` was `DONE` at the first check, the method returns and the only possible value for `state` in the rest of the method is `INIT` (by type narrowing). It does not consider that the value can still be changed to `DONE` by other code and "optimizes away" the second `if self.state is State.DONE` statement.

The error can be silenced by adding `# type: ignore [comparison-overlap]`. However, mypy will still not check the rest of that `if` statement which contains an obvious type error, for which no error message is generated.

How can we indicate to mypy (or other type checkers) that the variable can change its value after it has been accessed once, and that the body of the second `if` statement must be checked, analogous to e.g. the `volatile` keyword in the C language?

Comment: I would consider this as a false positive in mypy. Coroutine path evaluation might be tricky, but [the false positive shows up even with non-coroutine code](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=a9512952bb2ca682accd2ed1f8ad3dd6), not recognising that an instance method could change the state.

Comment: Wow, it's definitely a `mypy` bug. Please consider opening a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

The variable can be forced to be evaluated again by moving the comparison into a (local) function:

```
def check_twice(self) -> None:

    def done() -> bool:
        return self.state is State.DONE

    if done():
        print("DONE at first try")
        return

    self.work()

    if done():
        x: int = "x"  # mypy will now check this
        print("DONE at second try")
        return

    print("not DONE after second try")
```

Now mypy will report the type error in the second `if` statement:

```
$ mypy --strict-equality volatile.py 
volatile.py:29: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
```